# Editing my If statement also ideas about to grab a files date then move file

Tags: bash

```
 GNU nano 2.2.6                           File:     years.sh                                                            

#!/bin/bash

# When a match is not found, just present nothing.
shopt -s nullglob

# Match all .wav files containing the date format.
files=(*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.wav)

if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "no file"
fi




for file in "${files[@]}"; do
# We get the date part by part
file_date=''
# Sleep it to parts.
IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
        # Break from the loop if a match is found
    if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        file_date=$t
        break
    fi
done
# If a value was not assigned, then show an error message and continue to the next file.
# Just making sure there is nothing in Array and date before it moves on
```

Before adding this if statement if worked perfect for files that have YYYYMMDD.wav format.

```
if [[ -z $file_date ]]; then

# this print $6 could be print $5 or $7 depending on your OS

another_file_date=`ls -l --time-style=long-iso | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d '-'`

file_year=${file_date:0:4}
file_month=${file_date:4:2}



mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

echo "Moving: ./"$file "to: " "./"$file_year"/"$file_month
mv  "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"

    continue
fi
```

End of new statement

```
file_year=${file_date:0:4}
file_month=${file_date:4:2}




mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

# -- is just there to not interpret filenames starting with - as options.

echo "Moving: ./"$file "to: " "./"$file_year"/"$file_month
mv  "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"
done
```

When I run this code I get no error but I does not move my meetme files.
I have a file called meetme93238927832783.wav... I wanna grab the modify date or when the file was created and move the mive into a DIR that it year/month. When I run this code it just says no file with is my first if statement.... now before I added the new if statement it work fine with a YYYYMMDD.wav format

Comment: Note your header has `!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. It seems to me, that you want to copy `meetme.wav` to `$file_year/$file_month` based on its modification date. You know how to get the date string, how to split it into month and year and how to move the file, so what exactly is your problem. And please change your question title to something that relates to the actual problem.

Comment: I want it to move the Meetmeet me file but It will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify part of  your script file (the `if` and `continue` part) as the following,

```
if [[ -z $file_date ]]; then

   # this print $6 could be print $5 or $7 depending on your OS

    another_file_date=`ls -l --time-style=long-iso | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d '-'`

    file_year=${file_date:0:4}
    file_month=${file_date:4:2}
    file_day=${file_date:6:2}


    mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

    echo "Moving: ./"$file "to: " "./"$file_year"/"$file_month
    mv  "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"${file_year}${file_month}${file_day}.wav"

   continue
fi
```

and make sure the `print $6` is correct (this is test on linux, on Solaris or AIX the number `6` should be different).

Comment: I do not care about the day just year and month. Right now I have two files ... file 1 format is YYYYMMDD.wav and another meetme.wav .. when I run this script it moves all YYYYMMDD.wav in DIR YYYY/MM whihc I want.. Now I want to move meetme.wav but I need to know the YYYY and MM to move it into my DIR YYYY/MM/Filename

Comment: what this `YYYY` and `MM` comes from since it is not shown in the file name? do you want this refer to the last modified time of the file? or the current system date?

Comment: Example file 1 20130413.wav this file will then move into DIR 2013/04 all because the format of the file is YYYYMMDD.wav unlike meetme there is no date format in the file name so I need the last modified date and then change the name to the YYYYMMDD date

Comment: try my answer but first comment out the `mv` part, just `echo` to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

you could use find command searching for whole names and then move them

```
find <yourdir> -wholename '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.wav' -exec mv {} <your-dest-dir> ';'
```